# Run a regex replace while ignoring (but preserving) a certain character

Tags: javascript, regex

I think this is easier explained with some examples so...

```
"*X*helXlo** my \\X world" => "<b>*X*helXlo**</b> my \\X world"
"**helXlo** my \\X world"  => "<b>hello</b> my \\X world"
```

That is I sort of want something like

```
str.replace(/(X)?\*(X)?\*(.*)\*(X)?\*(X)?/g, "<b>$1*$2*$3*$4*$5</b>");
```

but ideally less ugly (looking more like the natural `replace(/(\*\*.*\*\*)/g, "<b>$1</b>")`). Is this possible?

Comment: you want a pretty regex?  Are you sure you're using the right language?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you're asking for, you definitely don't need all those groups. You could just do this:

```
str.replace(/X?\*X?\*.*\*X?\*X?/g, "<b>$&</b>")
```

It's essentially the same pattern, just without the groups. `$&` represents the entire matched substring.

Alternatively, you could write this as:

```
str.replace(/(X?\*){2}.*(\*X?){2}/g, "<b>$&</b>")
```

Comment: I know that you can use `$&`, what I do not like is typing X all over the place, I would like it to be explicit

Comment: @AaronYodaiken Well you can reduce it down to only having to write `X` twice. See my updated answer.